# Method 'HttpBaseProtocolFilter.put_CookieUsageBehavior(HttpCookieUsageBehavior)' was not included in compilation

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, uwp, system.net.httpwebrequest

I am working on Xamarin application - UWP, while in debug mode everything is working fine. Once I switch it to "Release" mode the application started crashing.

After some divedeep, I can see "***Method 'HttpBaseProtocolFilter.put_CookieUsageBehavior(HttpCookieUsageBehavior)' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in HttpClientHandler.InitRTCookieUsageBehaviorHelper().*** " exception.

I have checked the nuget "[System.Net.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http/)", it is updated to the latest version.

Am I missing something? Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My project had target build as "Windows 10 build 10240" and after updating it to "Windows 10 build 17763", it got resolved. 
However solution given by @lindexi, somehow that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

That is the .NET Native do. And it will remove some "unused" code. And you should add the Default.rd.xml file to tell the tool which you are use. See [Runtime Directives (rd.xml) Configuration File Reference | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/runtime-directives-rd-xml-configuration-file-reference)

Could you try to add this code?

```xml
 <Namespace Name="System.Net" Dynamic="Required All" Serialize="Required Public" Browse="Required All" Activate="Required All" />
```

Maybe you should try to add some namespace and sorry I can not find your problem in my devices and I can not test my code

I don't know if your question is what this blog says, [Migrating Your Windows Store App to .NET Native | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/migrating-your-windows-store-app-to-net-native#HttpClient)

> In .NET Native, the HttpClientHandler class internally uses WinINet (through the HttpBaseProtocolFilter class) instead of the WebRequest and WebResponse classes used in the standard .NET for Windows Store apps. WinINet doesn't support all the configuration options that the HttpClientHandler class supports. As a result:
>
> Some of the capability properties on HttpClientHandler return false on .NET Native, whereas they return true in the standard .NET for Windows Store apps.
>
> Some of the configuration property get accessors always return a fixed value on .NET Native that is different than the default configurable value in .NET for Windows Store apps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I tried it but it did do anything in my case.

Comment: @PranayDeep, Does the problem only occurs in current version ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Yes. Still unable to fix